# how to open sub sub routes with angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular2-routing, angular8

I've been trying to open my angular sub routes but the url changes but the page itself does not show. My routing page is

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AdminPage } from './admin/admin.page';
import { AdminDashboardPage } from './adminComponents/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.page';
import {AdminPermissionPage} from './adminComponents/admin-permission/admin-permission.page';
import {SchoolListPage} from './components/school-list/school-list.page';
import {StudentListPage} from './components/student-list/student-list.page';
import {TeacherListPage} from './components/teacher-list/teacher-list.page';
import {CoursesListPage} from './components/courses-list/courses-list.page';
import {LoginPage} from './components/login/login.page';
import {REditorPage} from './r-editor/r-editor.page';
import {RSchoolPage} from './r-school/r-school.page';
import {RSchoolStaffPage} from './r-school-staff/r-school-staff.page';
import {RTeacherPage} from './r-teacher/r-teacher.page';
import {RStudentsPage} from './r-students/r-students.page';
import {AddCoursePage} from './r-teacher-components/add-course/add-course.page'
import {AboutPage} from './components/about/about.page';
import {SchoolsPage} from './components/schools/schools.page';
import {ContactPage} from './components/contact/contact.page';
import {RegisterPage} from './components/register/register.page';
import {StudentPageCourseListPage} from './components/student-page-course-list/student-page-course-list.page';


import { AdminGuard } from './admin.guard';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginPage,
    pathMatch:"full"
  },
  {
    path:'admin',
    redirectTo:'admin/dashboard',
    pathMatch:'full'
  },
  {
    path:'editor',
    redirectTo:'editor/dashboard',
    pathMatch:'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminPage,
    //canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardPage,pathMatch:"full" },
      {
        path: 'school-list',
      component: SchoolListPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'student-list',
        component: StudentListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'teacher-list',
        component: TeacherListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'courses-list',
        component: CoursesListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'permissions',
        component: AdminPermissionPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'editor',
    component:REditorPage,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardPage,pathMatch:"full" },
      {
        path: 'school-list',
      component: SchoolListPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'student-list',
        component: StudentListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'teacher-list',
        component: TeacherListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'courses-list',
        component: CoursesListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'permissions',
        component: AdminPermissionPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'rschool',
    component:RSchoolPage,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardPage,pathMatch:"full" },
      {
        path: 'school-list',
      component: SchoolListPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'student-list',
        component: StudentListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'teacher-list',
        component: TeacherListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'courses-list',
        component: CoursesListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'permissions',
        component: AdminPermissionPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'rschoolstaff',
    component:RSchoolStaffPage,
    children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardPage,pathMatch:"full" },
      {
        path: 'school-list',
      component: SchoolListPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'student-list',
        component: StudentListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'teacher-list',
        component: TeacherListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'courses-list',
        component: CoursesListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      },
      {
        path: 'permissions',
        component: AdminPermissionPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'rteacher',
  component: RTeacherPage,
  children: [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardPage,pathMatch:"full" },
    {
      path: 'school-list',
    component: SchoolListPage,
    pathMatch:"full"
    },
    {
      path: 'student-list',
      component: StudentListPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
    },
    {
      path: 'teacher-list',
      component: TeacherListPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
    },
    {
      path: 'courses-list',
      component: CoursesListPage,
      children: [
        {
          path:"add-course",
          component:AddCoursePage
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: 'permissions',
      component: AdminPermissionPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
    }
  ]

  },
  {
    path: 'rstudents',
  component:RStudentsPage,
  children: [
    { path: 'dashboard', component: AdminDashboardPage,pathMatch:"full" },
    {
      path: 'school-list',
    component: SchoolListPage,
    pathMatch:"full"
    },
    {
      path: 'student-list',
      component: StudentListPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
    },
    {
      path: 'teacher-list',
      component: TeacherListPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
    },
    {
      path: 'courses-list',
      component: CoursesListPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
    },
    {
      path: 'permissions',
      component: AdminPermissionPage,
      pathMatch:"full"
    }
  ]

  },
  {
    path: 'add-school',
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/add-school/add-school.module').then( m => m.AddSchoolPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterPage,
    pathMatch:"full",
    children: [
      {
        path: 'student-page-course-list',
        component: StudentPageCourseListPage,
        pathMatch:"full"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutPage,
    pathMatch:"full"
  },
  {
    path: 'schools',
    component: SchoolsPage,
    pathMatch:"full"
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: ContactPage,
    pathMatch:"full"
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }),
    TranslateModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

For rteacher, I have a sub route for course-list and then course-list also has a sub route called add-course.I cant access the add-course page using my ionic navigation. Can an angular developer show me how to access the sub sub route?

course-list.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-courses-list',
  templateUrl: './courses-list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./courses-list.page.scss'],
})
export class CoursesListPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toAddCourse(){
     this.router.navigate(['rteacher/courses-list/add-course'])
   }
}
```

course-list.page

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    <ion-title>Courses list</ion-title>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <div class="add_role" (click)="toAddCourse()">
    <div class="add">
      <p>Add a new Course</p>
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="courses">

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: means you want to open the child page?

Comment: you want to open child page inside of parent page?

Comment: I want to open the add-course page since its a child of course-list. I want the cadd-course page to take over the screen

Answer (score 0):

**In app.routing.ts add your add-course page component route in the children section**

```
  {
      path: 'courses-list',
      redirectTo: 'CoursesListPage',  //here write your courses list page component name
      pathMatch: 'full',
  },
   children: [
      {
      path: 'add-coursePage',
      component: AddCoursePage,     //here write your add-coursePage component name
      data: {
          title: 'AddCoursePage'
      }
  },
```

Comment: children section under which route?? I am still having a hard time understanding

Comment: if you look at my code, add-course is already a child of courses-list

Comment: @schoolofthought you mean ```this.router.navigate(['rteacher/courses-list/add-course'])``` this line add-course is already a child of courses-list ??

Comment: yes, add-course is already a child of courses-list. take a look at the code that i wrote. its a su sub route.

Comment: @schoolofthought no I think that is wrong please comment this ```this.router.navigate(['rteacher/courses-list/add-course'])```  line and set the add-coursepage inside the course list page as I posted my answer

Comment: this is how I've written it. {
      path: 'courses-list',
      component: CoursesListPage,
      children: [
        {
          path:"add-course",
          component:AddCoursePage
        }
      ]
    }   how should i write it?

Comment: @schoolofthought    ```{ path: 'courses-list',redirectTo: 'CoursesListPage', component: CoursesListPage, children: [ { path:"add-course", component:AddCoursePage } ] }``` you miss this line ```,redirectTo: 'CoursesListPage'```

Comment: error says "Invalid configuration of route: redirectTo and children cannot be used together"

Comment: @schoolofthought ```export const routes: Routes = [```

Comment: not working at all. look at my code please. You did not read my route code

Comment: @schoolofthought refer this link helpful of your question ```https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-child-routes-nested-routes/```